# Nvim lsp - change lspconfig diagnostic message location

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

i ran into a problem, when im using neovim (+ lspconfig with `hie` set up), i have diagnostics info inline, but sometime, i cant read the whole line:
[image]

is there a way for me to see the whole message? i searched on the net to find a way to put the message on a floating window/status line when i hover the line, but i couldnt find a solution.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()` command shows the full diagnostics in a floating window:
[image]

I bound the command to `\<space>e` as shown in [the lspconfig github](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#suggested-configuration) README and everything works fine.

**EDIT 9 may 2022**: In [this commit](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/commit/382712c4ecba5816f398379dd9d8c8200b025ca3), `vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()` changed to `vim.diagnostic.open_float()`, thanks @DarthVanger for pointing it out.

Comment: yeah. this is the only way where you can the virtual text from error wrapped very well to fit into the screen and to see the entire message

Comment: The linked github doesn't have `show_line_diagnostics()` binding example. I've ended up adding `buf_map(bufnr, "n", "<space>e", "<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()<CR>")` to `on_attach` in my `nvim` config

Answer (score 24):

To disable inline text, and do a diagnostic window on hover, just put these lines into lsp config:

```
vim.diagnostic.config({
  virtual_text = false
})

-- Show line diagnostics automatically in hover window
vim.o.updatetime = 250
vim.cmd [[autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * lua vim.diagnostic.open_float(nil, {focus=false})]]
```

More info can be found here: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/wiki/UI-Customization

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the diagnostic window is visible now, but the virtual text is shown yet :(.

Comment: If you want to disable the virtual text, use `vim.diagnostic.disable()`. Refer to [the docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/diagnostic.html#:~:text=disable(%7Bbufnr%7D%2C%20%7Bnamespace%7D)-,vim.diagnostic.disable(),-Disable%20diagnostics%20in) for more info

Comment: @Ali BEN AMOR that disables diagnostics completely.

Comment: I tried it and it works. As far as I understood his question, he wants only the floating panel to have the messages. So disabling the default one works (at least for me).
This is how I did it :
`vim.diagnostic.disable()`
`vim.cmd [[autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * lua vim.diagnostic.open_float(nil, {focus=false})]]`